# Execute next statement in While loop after recursion

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have function like below

```
function add(){
var isOk = true;

  while(isOk){
   add();         // calling my function again here based on some condition
   console.log('I can\'t reach this line');
   isOk = false;
  } 
}
add()  // calling function here
```

Now when i call my add function, is there a way i can reach my console.log statement here ?

Comment: No, as written there is not a way, because each recursive call will get stuck in the same loop. Each call to the function results in a new `isOk` variable.

Comment: You need to add a base condition to your recursion so that it doesn't loop forever. Something like this:
```js
if (foo == bar) add();
console.log("I can reach this line"
```

Comment: That function there is a infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

you could define few extra conditions to make it work

```
var isOk = true;
var loopCount = 0;
var loopMax = 10;
functon add() {
   loopCount++;
   if ( loopCount > loopMax ) 
     isOk = false;

     if (isOk) {
        add();
     } else {
       console.log('I can\'t reach this line');
      // isOk = false;
     }
  }
add();
```

Comment: I have to use while loop, i got it idea behind this. thank you